# Why always in the database, the DateTime property is null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, null

i 'm beginner in programming with MVC5.
I am working with MVC5 and Entity framework 6.
I have a class and a DateTime property like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
public DateTime? BirthDay { get; set; }
```

my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MelliCode,EnCode,grade,quota,password,FName,Lname,shenasname,FatehrName,sex,tel,mobile,ResAddress,WorkAddress")] Expert expert)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Experts.Add(expert);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(expert);
    }
```

and my view like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDay, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDay, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDay, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

However, after the run of the page and enter personal information in the database is inserted to null for Birthday!!!why?

Comment: Please add your form, controller and data layer code too.

Comment: are you getting all other fields into the database?

Comment: yes .all data is correct except birthday

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Remove your `[Bind]` attribute - your excluding property `BirthDay`. The read [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) and never again use `[Bind]`

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Include  is missing BirthDay. can you post your entire model actions ( including httppost] and your full view with form tags ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem
I had forgotten Birthday in [Bind] attribute

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BirthDay,MelliCode,EnCode,grade,quota,password,FName,Lname,shenasname,FatehrName,sex,tel,mobile,ResAddress,WorkAddress")] Expert expert)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Experts.Add(expert);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: so like i said Include was missing Birthday

Comment: Don't use bind, create model object for data.